# Mat stepper done icon is out of circle

Tags: angular, mat, stepper

Hello i have trouble using mat stepper in angular..

```
<div class="container text-center mt-5" >
  <p>E-SNEAKERS</p>
  <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>

    <mat-step label="Step 1">
      Step 1 content
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Step 2">
      Step 2 content
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Step 3">
      You are now done.
    </mat-step>

  </mat-horizontal-stepper>
</div>
```

Done step icon is out of circle..
Component doesnt contain any css..

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqrCc.png)

Comment: did you give padding after each mat stepper? like this    <div style="padding-top: 3%;">
          Step 1 content
      </div>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this code works:

```
   <mat-step label="Step 1">
      <div style="padding-top: 3%;">
          Step 1 content
      </div>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Step 2">
      <div style="padding-top: 3%;">
          Step 2 content
      </div>
    </mat-step>

    <mat-step label="Step 3">
      <div style="padding-top: 3%;">
          You are now done.
      </div>
    </mat-step>
```

While Designing/Templating you need to take of these:

Note 1: While transforming Mat based styling - always change in Local/Component level scss,

Note 2 : If you want to transform at Global level use **ng-deep**. The further Information will be available in: https://angular.io/guide/component-styles

Comment: Did you increase the padding or  margin ? Would you create a Stackblitz Demo?

Comment: I had  this inside global css mat-icon {
  transform: translate(0px, 0px)!important;
  user-select: none;
} ,but anyway thanks

Comment: is it working now?While Designing/Templating you need to take of these  Note 1: While transforming Mat based styling - always change in local/component level scss, Note 2 : If you want to transform at Global level use ng-deep. The further Information will be available in:  https://angular.io/guide/component-styles